# scanf() goes without taking any input

Tags: c, gdb, scanf

I have C code doing some calculations (irrelevant to my question, I believe ). The program will ask for some parameters for calculation. The problem is when I running the codes, a scanf("%c", &ch) isn't working properly.

I'm interested in whether you can reproduce this problem because it seems that I didn't get anything wrong, am I?

I posted an compilable and shortened version of my program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
        float Dia_MM, Dia_I, Se1, Se, Sut = 75.00;
        float Ka, Kb, Kc, Kd, Ke, Kf;
        char Ch;
        char Bt;
        float Reli;
        printf("Please input the surface condition of the shaft: G, M, H or A\n");
        scanf("%c", &Ch);
//      getchar();
        printf("Please input the diameter of the shaft in inch\n");
        scanf("%f", &Dia_I);
        printf("Please specify whether your shaft is in bending (B) or torsion (T)");
        scanf("%c", &Bt);// THIS LINE IS JUST SKIPPED
        exit(0);
}
```

The GDB log is listed:

```
  Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:25
  25        float Dia_MM, Dia_I, Se1, Se, Sut = 75.00;
  (gdb) n
  30        printf("Please input the surface condition of the shaft: G, M, H or A\n");
  (gdb) n
  Please input the surface condition of the shaft: G, M, H or A
  31        scanf("%c", &Ch);
  (gdb) G
  Undefined command: "G".  Try "help".
  (gdb) n 
  G
  33        printf("Please input the diameter of the shaft in inch\n");
  (gdb) n
  Please       input the diameter of the shaft in inch
  34        scanf("%f", &Dia_I);
  (gdb) n
  4.5
  35        printf("Please specify whether your shaft is in bending (B) or torsion (T)");
  (gdb) n
  36            scanf("%c", &Bt);
  (gdb) n                            //PROBLEM HERE. SCANF() GOES BEFORE TAKE ANY INPUT.
  37        exit(0);
```

Comment: "Please specify whether your shaft is in bending or torsion." *chortle*

Comment: @x0n: I would be more worried about vibration :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf()` does not consume trailing newlines. The skipped `scanf()` receives the newline from the *previous* line typed by the user and terminates without receiving more input as you would expect...

`scanf()` is a bit cumbersome with newlines. A possible solution would be to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to get a line from the console and then employ `sscanf()` to parse the received string.

Another, more targeted, solution would be to use `" %c"` in the format string of the last `scanf()` call. The `%c` format specifier does not consume leading whitespace on its own, which is why it gets the remaining newline, rather than a character typed by the user.

Comment: So you mean change it to         printf("Please specify whether your shaft is in bending (B) or torsion (T)\n");? I tried but still the same problem

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey: In case you missed it, I have edited my answer with a couple of possible solutions...

Answer (score 4):

As **thkala** told above `scanf()` does not consume trailing newlines.But there is another way to absorb the newline from the previous line using `\n` like that `scanf("%c\n",...)`.

Comment: Use `%*c` to read a character without assigning the result to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```